# Displaying angular 2 inputs as strings

Tags: angular, typescript, type-conversion

I am working on a project that uses angular 2 and a having an issue. The client wants the numbers that they enter on the input tags to be displayed as strings with commas and decimals. Because we are sending and getting this data from a database they are stored as numbers. For readability they want them displayed with commas but I cannot actually change the value to a string since that will cause issues with back end calculations. For this reason I think that using angular pipes will not work because this will convert the number to a string. I am also looping through large amounts of data so this is not a few numbers that I can just convert and call it good. I need a more global solution. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pipe` and `regex` to separate the input number three by three and set the corresponding character.

pipe

```
transform(value: number, format: string): string {
    return (+value || 0).toFixed(2)
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,')
      .replace(/(?=((,\d{3}){2}))/, '*')
      .replace('*,', "'");
  }
```

input **1000000**

output **1'000,000.00**

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-amount)